# Format PHP database data

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

What I would like to know is when I grab data from a Database how can I format it with PHP so it looks nice. All i seem to be getting is a Blank white page and when i inspect the page with google chromes inspect element it says that i've got a 500 internal error.

For example, I'm using PDO to connect to the database. Heres my code:

```
<?php
$hostname='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='root';

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=fitness", $username, $password);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fitness";
$fitnessResult = $dbh->query($s ql);
$fitness = $dbh->fetchObject($fitnessResult);
foreach ($fitness AS $fit) {
$fitnessArray[] = ['name' => $fit->name, 'id' => $fit->description];
}
$dbh = null;
}
catch (PDOexception $e) {
echo "Error is: " . $e-> etmessage();
}
```

and here is my html im using the twitter bootstrap framework.

```
<?php
include'inc/connect.inc.php';
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Fitness</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-  theme.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">
<?php foreach ($fitnessArray AS $fitness) { echo '<h2>'. $fitness['name'] .'</h2>'; echo '<p>' . $fitness['description'] . '</p>';} ?>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <p>Dummy Text</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So how would I put the name into a H1 tag and the description into P tag.

Thanks

Comment: looks like you are already doing that, whats teh problem?

Comment: You don't "format in php" - php is a server side language - the design and visual stuff is done on the client side (using mainly images and the syntax of HTML and CSS)

Comment: your question is not clear at all

Comment: @Dagon All it does is return a blank white page and when I inspect element in chrome I get a 500 internal error??

Comment: well perhaps share that information in the begging next time ..

Comment: @YaronU yeah I know thanks my explanations aren't very good at all. sorry!

Comment: you need to set error checking and display on so you can find the errors

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like the following which keeps the objects and fetchs all in an arrary

```
$fitnessResult = $dbh->query($sql);
$fitnessArray = $fitnessResult->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

then in your html

```
<?php foreach ($fitnessArray AS $fitness): ?>
  <h2><?=$fitness->name ?></h2>
  <p><?=$fitness->description ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[see official docs for fetchAll()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: Thanks, i've tried it but I still get a 500 internal error.

Comment: @Phopixel - put `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your file and see if there is any more useful error reporting. It might be you server config is wrong (i.e Apache)